# try/except doesnt behaves the same on 2 different projects

Tags: python

In one code that is the server there is a function that creates or updates a record on the DB like this:

```
try:
    self.objects(uaid=uaid, chidmessageid=" ").update(chids__add={channel_id})
    return True
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    try:
        self.create(uaid=uaid, chidmessageid=" ", chids={channel_id})
        return True
    except LWTException as a:
        print(a)
        return False
```

and on other project that I use to unit-test those functions before inserting the code to the real server(also is faster to test), both point to the same DB.
In my test code works but on the server doesn't

in both they raise the except but on the server code using the python debugger noticed that after getting the first except for the update() try's to do the second func create() gets another except but breaks before printing and on my testing project gets the first except then try's to do the create() and works. its the same code not a single change, its driving me crazy.

Comment: sorry just edit the question

Comment: is this django?

Comment: There is not enough context here; what are uaid and channel_id (have you tried printing them), and how is the database set up? What is self, and where do the attributes objects and create come from (i.e., what (presumed) ORM are you using)?

Comment: As an aside, you really want to catch a *specific* exception, not a general `Exception`. Now you can't see if, possibly, on one machine one type of exception is raised, and another machine a different exception type is raised (thus making your unit test useless).